# Tag reorganization needed: error; error-messages; messages

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Despite the popularity of m_goldberg's proposal I have misgivings about eliminating the [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag by way of making it a synonym.  I offer a counter-proposal in my own answer.  Please vote it up or down accordingly.

---

Presently there are 52 questions tagged [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) and 219 question tagged [error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages).

The summaries read:

- Questions seeking help understanding error messages and fixing errors.
- For questions on interpreting existing error messages that you have encountered, as well as writing and managing messages, ...

We also have [messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messages) with 29 questions and a summary of:

- Questions on the internal error messages of Mathematica.

Clearly there is duplication, but also some things are missing:

1. Not all messages are errors
2. Not all errors produce messages

I think these tags need to be reorganized and clarified.  I am soliciting proposals.

Comment: I would like a tag about _generating_ error messages. Is there one already?

Comment: "as well as writing and managing messages" - suggests `messages` as a tag, whereas the other summaries suggest `error-messages`. To me the problem lies in the summary of the tag for [error-messages](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages)

Comment: @belisarius Surely `messages` is currently appropriate for questions about generating messages, error or otherwise, and that is how it is already being used.  I expect to correct its description as part of this clean-up.  Are you in favor of an explicit `message-generation` tag?  I am wondering if we should even have an `error-messages` tag as it appears to confound two categories: messages and errors, which are not one and the same.  However removing that tag would require substantial manual retagging I believe.  Please post an answer if you have a clear picture of what you think we need.

Comment: @blochwave In your view how should `error-messages` be used, if it all?  Only for questions about understanding existing messages?  Currently it is more broadly used than that so a lot of retagging would be needed.  Should we try to have a `understanding-messages`/`generating-messages` dichotomy, or perhaps we should have only one `messages` tag and *also* add `error` when it seems appropriate?  Again, if you have a clear picture of how you think this should work please post an answer.

Comment: I don't care much in this case about the tag's names, but (I believe)  there should be two different tags: one for asking questions about how to generate/ manage messages, and another one for asking for help about understanding MMa's own messages. The "error" part is a semantic issue, as both Mma and the user may generate messages for reporting errors or for any other purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm with belisarius on this one really.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Am I right, that [tag:error] should not be used for [a questions about `ErrorListPlot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96512/18476)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After consideration I propose slightly different synonym structure from what m_goldberg describes.  I feel that [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) is a clean and natural tag that applies to message interpretation (*"what does this error mean?"*) *as well as* other kinds of errors that should not *automatically* be remapped to [message-interpretation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-interpretation).  A solution to this perceived problem would be:

- [message-coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-coding) <-- [message-generation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-generation) <-- [messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messages)
- [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) <-- [error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages) <-- [message-interpretation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-interpretation)

I could see some number of questions incorrectly tagged [message-coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-coding) as a result of this but it appears that [messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messages) is already a more rarely used tag so the problem should be quite limited.

Comment: I could live with this without suffering any heart-burn, but ask you to consider [message-coding] <-- [messages] as a defense against the "why is my code generating these error messages?" leading to the  ]message-generation] tag.

Comment: @m_goldberg Do you mean simply add the synonym `message-coding` to `message-generation`?  That would be fine and I'll add that to this proposal if that is what you mean.  Or do you mean replace `message-generation` with `message-coding` and make `message-generation` a synonym of it?

Comment: I was thinking of eliminating [message-generation] altogether because of the confusion you pointed out; i.e., [message-coding] <-- [messages] in place of [message-generation] <-- [messages]. But [message-coding] <-- [messages]<--[message-generation] would be OK.

Comment: @m_goldberg Proposal updated.  Let me know if you think of any other issues with this.

Comment: Looks good. I have no further issues at this point.

Comment: Upvoted, I believe this is as clear as one can get on this terrain

Answer (score 9):

I'm with belisarius on this issue, too. I suggest

- [message-interpretation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-interpretation) with synonyms [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) and [error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages)
- [messge-generation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messge-generation) with synonym [message-coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-coding)

Comment: And blacklist `message`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. No, make it a synonym of `message-interpretation`.

Comment: +1, but I felt that [tag:message] should refer to `Message`, so that I thought it should be a synonym of [tag:message-generation]. I suppose I'm now in favor of blacklisting.

Comment: @m_goldberg Despite the popularity of your answer I continue to have misgivings about this scheme.  I posted a counter-proposal.  Would you please consider it and give me feedback?  Either way this retagging is going to be a lot of work and I want to get it right the first time.